# iOS safe area not working on real devices

Tags: ios, autolayout, iphone-x

I tried to adapt my app to work correctly on iPhone X, so used safe area in the XIB files with some change in constraints. when I test the result on simulator it works as expected, but not the case on real device (iPhone 6).
I cleaned the project and re-run but didn't work.

[image]

real device (iPhone 6)

[image: real device (iPhone 6)]

Comment: A safe area are part of auto layout, which means constraints. Where's yours? Hard to duplicate an issue you are having (nobody else is) without that.

Answer (score 0):

Safe area layout is working fine. I think you are using iOS 10 or older in iPhone6. For versions previous to iOS11 safe area won't work, you have to programmatically check your iOS version and use NSLayoutConstraint to add height anchor.